# Buttons break when styling

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

Before I even start, here's my JSFiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/on652pk6/`with css`

https://jsfiddle.net/8zq922nd/1/ `without css`

the buttons don't load properly in jsfiddle because I wasn't sure how to reference the image files for the buttons, but you can see how it's supposed to look at officialsamsmith.com

so here's my problem: All of my buttons at the top should link to their respective websites, and they do, but only when no styling is applied. As soon as I style the buttons, they break. I would honestly start over from scratch on the CSS if I had to, but before I switched to a new host I did not have this issue. The only thing I've changed since I remember them working (its been a few months since I've worked on this project) is that the buttons (which are png files) were permalinked before, and now I refer directly to the file.

I really hope that i'm not missing something extrememly obvious here, but thank you for your help in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#inprogress` was covering up the links. Do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/on652pk6/2/

```
.buttonbox {
     text-align: center;
     height: 100px;
     width: 100%;
     padding-top:20;
        }
#inprogress {
     padding-top:0px;
     font-size: 75px;
     position: relative;
     margin:auto;
     text-align:center;
     letter-spacing: 30px;
}
```

Remove `position: absolute` from `#buttonbox` and remove the padding on `#inprogress`.

Comment: Wow I feel silly now! thank you so much! - now the question remains why that worked before but doesn't work now?